What does the result of the type guard function mean like "variable is Enum"?
What does the result of the type guard function mean like "variable is Enum"?
I want to check if a variable is one of the value in enam.
enum TestEnum {
  value1Key = 'value1Str',
  value2Key = 'value2Str'
}

function typeGuard(value: string): value is TestEnum {}

What does the expression value is TestEnum indicate? Is the object like TestEnum or does it have a value in TestEnum? Maybe it's better to use a type like (typeof TestEnum)[keyof typeof TestEnum]?
I want to understand if there is a difference between isEnumValue1 and isEnumValue2
enum Fruit {
  Apple = 'apple',
  Banana = 'banana',
  Orange = 'orange'
}

function isEnumValue1(value: any): value is (typeof Fruit)[keyof typeof Fruit] {
  return Object.values(Fruit).includes(value);
}

function isEnumValue2(value: any): value is Fruit {
  return Object.values(Fruit).includes(value);
}


Are you trying to ask about type predicates?

@jonrsharpe I'm wondering if there is a difference between value is (typeof TestEnum)[keyof typeof TestEnum] and value is TestEnum. Thanks.

TestEnum and (typeof TestEnum)[keyof typeof TestEnum] are the same type.

So the question doesn't really have much to do with type guards and instead has to do with what the type named MyEnum means?
